# Zip compare between integer and pointer

Tags: c++

I am writing code to compare a zipcode integer input (`int z`) and the zipcode of the input `ZNode object *n`. When comparing them I keep getting error of comparison between `z` and `ZNode n`. How can I compare an integer and a pointer?

```cpp
ZNode AVLTree::*findZip(int z, ZNode *n){

    if(z==n->zip || n==NULL){
        return(n);
    }
    else if(z < n->zip){
        findZip(z, n->left);
    }
    else if(z > n->zip){
        findZip(z, n->right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Java doesn't support the C-style dereference arrow.  Use the dot operator instead, e.g. `if(z==n.zip || n==NULL) { ... }`.

Comment: Eclipse is just your development environment and can be used to develop in many different programming languages. Which language is this?

Comment: this is in c++, my bad for not clarifying before

Comment: Please include the declaration of ZNode. What does it look like?

Comment: The very first line of code in the function is wrong. The null-pointer check has to be *first*. Otherwise, if `n` is NULL, what's going to happen when you try and dereference it? Boom.

Comment: You need to return znode*

Answer (score 0):

Please see fixes and comments below

```
ZNode AVLTree::findZip(int z, ZNode *n){ // ::findZip - No *

    if(n==NULL || z==n->zip){ // Need to check for NULL first - perhaps nullptr
        return(n);
    }
    else if(z < n->zip){
        return findZip(z, n->left); // You need to return an answer!
    }
    else { // Just do findZip for the right or equals - for equals the above will match
        return findZip(z, n->right); // Again return an answer
    }
}
```

PS. Probably better not to use recursion. Recursion tends to break on large trees.